# Django - dynamic number of fields on a form

Tags: python, django

I've spent last 24 hours bashing my head against the wall trying to solve this problem. I already know that on this board there are at least 10 similar questions. Why I'm still asking? Well, because no solution seems to work :). Here's the code:

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    some_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.fields['file_field_%d' % i] = forms.FileField()
```

This code renders only some_field, and nothing else. It doesn't seem to care I'm adding 10 filefields. Django ver is 1.3.1

Comment: That looks ok to me. Can you update your question to include the code you're using to display the model form?

Comment: Well actually that's all the code :) + this: class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyAdminForm

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to use the form in the Django admin ... that makes things trickier. As I said before, your model form looks fine to me, and would work in a regular view. I don't know where the problem is in the Django admin. You can start digging around [`options.py`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py), hope that somebody else on Stack Overflow knows the answer, or take it as a sign that you're trying to do too much customisation in the Django admin, and that it's time to write your own view.

Comment: That was actually the idea I came up with - that maybe I should write my own view, but on the other hand it's hard to believe that django developers made such a bug...

Comment: You'll come across issues like this from time to time. It doesn't mean that the Django admin is bad, just that it wasn't designed with this use case in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Adding fields before calling `__init__()` of base class worked for me.

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    some_field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.fields['file_field_%d' % i] = forms.FileField()

        super(MyAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you don't need variable number of fields in every instance of the form, modifying only the `base_fields` class property should work too.

```
class MyAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    some_field = forms.CharField()

for i in range(0, 10):
    MyAdminForm.base_fields['file_field_%d' % i] = forms.FileField()
```

Comment: I got error saying: 'MyAdminForm' object has no attribute 'fields'. When I initialized fields before loop it didn't work also...

Comment: One more thing - these FileFields are being added to self.fields - I looped over it in some core django method, and they were there.